# Remove previous event listener and add new event Listener

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

I am creating a drawing app in which I am trying to draw different shapes (rect, circle, line) on canvas depend on shapes button click. So, when I attach `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onmousemove`, on Canvas say on rect shape button click then It add Events on canvas and when I click say circle button it add mouse events for both rect and circle on canvas.So my question is how I can remove previous event or change its handler?

Source code on: 
https://github.com/anuj-jaryal/screenshot-chrome-extension/tree/add-cropping?files=1

Its a Chrome extension, so first setup in Chrome extension.

Comment: but I have to attach again new event listener.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve this, is not to change the event listener.

Use a flag, change him every time the user choose a new shape, and check the flag every time he clicked on the canvas.

```
let newWeDrawing = "circle";

function userChooseRect() {
    newWeDrawing = "rect"
}

function userClickedOnCanvas() {
    switch (newWeDrawing) {
        case "cirecle":
            drawCircle();
            break;
        case "rect":
            drawRect();
            break;
    }
}
```

Or, a better approach, is to use some hash table to describe the different options.

```
let newWeDrawing = 1;

function userChooseShape(idOfShape) {
    newWeDrawing = idOfShape;
}

function userClickedOnCanvas() {
    switch (newWeDrawing) {
        case 1:
            drawCircle();
            break;
        case 2:
            drawRect();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But In this approach also, event listener not remove previous events as I have different handler for different shape.

Comment: Yes, the idea here is *not* to have different hander on the Dom for every shape. This approach, of using flag, is more clean and more scalable. The Dom call *only one event* and you, inside the called function, choose  which function to invoke.